# JDA - get author of the message in GuildMessageReactionAdd / Discord

Tags: discord-jda

im trying to find out a way to get the author of the message that somebody has reacted to.

```
> e.getChannel().getHistory().getMessageById(e.getMessageId()).getAuthor();
```

this is what i've got but it returns null

Answer (score 0):

Use [GuildMessageReactionAddEvent#retrieveMessage](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/events/message/guild/react/GenericGuildMessageReactionEvent.html#retrieveMessage()):

```java
event.retrieveMessage().queue(message -> {
... code that uses the message ...
});
```